# Dudas en la aplicación de la función diff() a una columna de un DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.7, jupyter

Estoy intentando entender este script, y la sentencia en la que se aplica el método **.diff()** a una columna del DataFrame, me devuelve un resultado que no entiendo.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as pdr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Creamos el df para el análisis
ticker = "GME"
start='2000-01-01'
end='2020-12-31'

datos = pdr.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start = start, end = end)
dfSMA = datos[["Close"]] 

ventana_corta = 42
ventana_larga = 252
nom_val = "Close"
dfSMA["señal"]= 0.0

dfSMA['MA42'] = dfSMA[nom_val].rolling(ventana_corta, min_periods=1, center=False).mean().dropna()
dfSMA['MA252'] = dfSMA[nom_val].rolling(ventana_larga, min_periods=1, center=False).mean().dropna()


# Creamos la columna "señal", prescindiendo de 42 cotizaciones(ventana corta)
dfSMA["señal"][ventana_corta:] = np.where(dfSMA['MA42'][ventana_corta:]  > dfSMA['MA252'][ventana_corta:], 1.0, 0.0)   

# Generación de ordenes de compra / venta
dfSMA['posicion'] = dfSMA["señal"].diff()  #  dfSMA["señal"][1] - dfSMA["señal"][0] , anotada en hoy
```

Muestro a continuación el df con las columnas **señal** y **posicion**

dfSMA[["señal", "posicion" ]][53:65]

[image: columnas señal y posición]

Si he entendido bien, la función .diff() actúa de la manera siguiente:

```
dfSMA["señal"][1] - dfSMA["señal"][0] # anotada en la fila 0
```

Es decir, resta el valor en la fila **1** de la columna **señal**, del valor en la columna **0** de la columna **señal** y anota el resultado en la fila **o** de la columna **posición**, y así sucesivamente.

En la salida veo lo siguiente:

Entendamos por 0 en este ejemplo, la primera fila de la figura (la figura muestra datos desde la fila 53 hasta la 64.
posición [0] = 0-0
posición[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftZW2.png) = 1-0 = 1 sin embargo muestra un 0 en posición 1
posición[2] = 1 - 1 = 0, sin embargo muestra 1 en posición 2

Así podríamos seguir. ¿Qué no estoy entendiendo bien?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El método`.diff()` sirve para hallar diferencias entre datos. Si se usa sin ningún argumento, lo que hace es **computar la diferencia entre el dato de una columna y el mismo dato de la fila inmediatamente anterior.**

Siguiendo tu ejemplo:

```
             Close  señal   MA42    MA252   posicion
Date                    
2002-05-01  10.250  0.0 9.751071    9.755648    0.0
2002-05-02  10.415  0.0 9.764524    9.767636    0.0
2002-05-03  10.400  1.0 9.782976    9.778929    1.0
2002-05-06  10.875  1.0 9.811548    9.798158    0.0
2002-05-07  10.750  1.0 9.824405    9.814569    0.0
2002-05-08  11.200  1.0 9.842262    9.838051    0.0
2002-05-09  11.425  0.0 9.862262    9.864500    -1.0
2002-05-10  11.030  0.0 9.872500    9.883607    0.0
2002-05-13  10.750  0.0 9.878214    9.897581    0.0
2002-05-14  10.400  0.0 9.875833    9.905556    0.0
2002-05-15  9.925   0.0 9.869881    9.905859    0.0
2002-05-16  10.300  0.0 9.885357    9.911923    0.0
```

Vamos día por día:

- Día 1 de mayo: tenemos en la columna `posición` el valor `0.0`. Eso es porque si nos vamos al 30 de abril ejecutando `dfSMA.iloc[52]` obtendremos que `señal` es `0.0` y la diferencia entre 0 y 0 es 0
- Día 2 de mayo: en la columna `señal` el valor cero, y tenemos que el día 1 de mayo el valor era 0. Volvemos a hallar la diferencia, y `0-0 = 0`
- Día 3 de mayo: en la columna `señal` tenemos el valor uno, y el valor en esta misma columna anterior, el día 2 de mayo ,es cero. Hallamos la diferencia `1-0 = 1`
- Día 4 de mayo: en la columna `señal` tenemos el valor uno y el valor en esta misma columna anterior, el día 3 de mayo, es 1. Hallamos la diferencia `1-1 = 0`

Por tanto tu comprensión es ligeramente incorrecta:

> Es decir, resta el valor en la fila 1 de la columna señal, del valor en la columna 0 de la columna señal y anota el resultado en la fila o de la columna posición, y así sucesivamente.

En concreto:

> y anota el resultado en la fila o de la columna posición, y así sucesivamente.

NO, lo anota en la **fila uno (no cero) de la columna posición**

Es decir, cuando queremos calcular el día dos de mayo, usamos el uno de mayo para restarlo, y el resultado se guarda en la columna del dos de mayo (No en la del uno de mayo). Por eso **si coges todo tu `DataFrame`** desde el día 13 de febrero, y ves primer valor, te darás cuenta que es `NaN`. Es decir si ejecutas esto:

```
dfSMA.head()
```

**Salida:**

```
            Close   señal   MA42    MA252   posicion
Date                    
2002-02-13  10.050  0.0 10.0500 10.0500 NaN
2002-02-14  10.000  0.0 10.0250 10.0250 0.0
2002-02-15  9.950   0.0 10.0000 10.0000 0.0
2002-02-19  9.550   0.0 9.8875  9.8875  0.0
2002-02-20  9.875   0.0 9.8850  9.8850  0.0
```

El primer dato de la columna `posicion` es `NaN` porque tiene que usar el dato anterior para calcular el resultado. Como dicho dato no existe, porque este es el primer dato del `DataFrame` se anota `NaN`. Y se anota en la primera columna, que es en la que estamos, no en la anterior.

Puedes saber y ver más ejemplos sobre el método `.diff()` en la [documentación oficial de Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html)

Comment: Luego quedaría así: dfSMA["señal"][1] - dfSMA["señal"][0] y se anota en la fila 1

Comment: Así es, correcto!